# Bash Join command inserting delimiter characters into first element

Tags: text-processing, join

I have two files:

File1.txt:

```
510806153|1||||33245|65|6236067806|25001|7746250
510806153|1||||33245|65|6968349321|25001|8956584
```

File2.txt

```
510806153|||||
```

When I do `join -t \| -j 1 file1.txt file2.txt`,
I get this output:

```
|||||6153|1||||33245|65|6236067806|25001|7746250
|||||6153|1||||33245|65|6968349321|25001|8956584
```

But when I do `join -t \| -j 1 file2.txt file1.txt`,
I get the correct join:

```
510806153||||||1||||33245|65|6236067806|25001|7746250
510806153||||||1||||33245|65|6968349321|25001|8956584
```

Why is join adding vertical bars to the first command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `file1.txt` has CRLF line endings.

Comment: I don't have enough points to upvote your answer, but I did mark it as the solution. Thank you for sending me down this path. I wasn't aware that line endings influence how the join commands work. One of the files did have CRLF or `\r\n` line endings. I do know that after converting both files to just `\n` for line endings make the join work as expected. Thank you again.

Answer (score -1):

> Why is join adding pipes to the first command?

Because it combine 2 file, the adding pipe was data |||| from `file2.txt`

---

**Command Descriptions**

`-t \|` : take pipe | as delimiter, for easy read you can change with `-t"|"`

`-j 1`  : find the common field of column 1, you can delete this for easy read, as default *join* chose column 1 too

`file1.txt file2.txt` : get the data from file1 then combine to file2

---

**Value from command**

| Data | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Delimiter **-t** | `|` |
| Common Field **-j 1** | `510806153` |
| FILE1 (exclude common field and first `|`) | `1||||33245|65|6236067806|25001|7746250` `1||||33245|65|6968349321|25001|8956584` |
| FILE2 (exclude common field and first `|`) | `||||` |

Now lets look how data works

---

**1. COMMAND = `join -t \| -j 1 file1.txt file2.txt`**

**OUTPUT** = `Common Field` + `Delimiter`  + `FILE1` + `Delimiter`  + `FILE2`

**OUTPUT** = `510806153` + `|` + `1||||33245|65|6236067806|25001|7746250...` + `|` + `||||`

**OUTPUT** =

```
510806153|1||||33245|65|6236067806|25001|7746250|||||
510806153|1||||33245|65|6968349321|25001|8956584|||||
```

***NOTE :** Look like your output command 1 was wrong or because StackEchange formating*

---

**2. COMMAND = `join -t \| -j 1 file2.txt file1.txt`**

**OUTPUT** = `Common Field` + `Delimiter`  + `FILE2` + `Delimiter`  + `FILE1`

**OUTPUT** = `510806153` + `|` + `||||` + `|` + `1||||33245|65|6236067806|25001|7746250...`

**OUTPUT** =

```
510806153||||||1||||33245|65|6236067806|25001|7746250
510806153||||||1||||33245|65|6968349321|25001|8956584
```

For more detail & example : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-command-linux/

Comment: An ‘‘A’’ for effort — I applaud your level of detail and your presentation style.  Please continue to write and post answers like this.  But, sadly, you didn’t answer the question.  As far as I can see, all you have done is explain *why* the OP *should* have gotten the result that they were expecting, and, since the OP probably already understands that, it’s not very helpful.